# Minted shows formatted tex code instead of intended source

Tags: miktex, windows, minted, code

I use WinShell with PDFLatex on Windows 7. I managed to install Pygmentize and compile the minimum example without errors:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

inline: \mint{python}|import this|

\begin{minted}{c}
int main() {
    printf("hello, world");
    return 0;
}
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

However, the output is strange. It shows tex code in the document, which is nicely formatted as if it was Python code:

[image: result]

Any idea how this could happen? Please comment, if more information is needed.

**Update**

I compile via WinShell, my PDFLatex command line looks like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe" -shell-escape -aux-directory=./.aux -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=-1 "%s.tex"
```

Comment: I'm afraid `minted` is not very well behaving on Windows.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: This document works fine under Windows--I just compiled it.  How are you compiling the document?  It looks like the Pygments output is somehow being included in your document verbatim.

Comment: I added the command line

Comment: Related:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112953/error-when-using-minted-package-and-output-directory-option?noredirect=1#comment249149_112953

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that MiKTeX's `-aux-directory` option doesn't work with `minted`'s use of pygmentize.  Apparently, this option causes problems with packages that use external programs.  See https://code.google.com/p/minted/issues/detail?id=37.

Comment: Removing the `-aux-directory` option solved the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: As far as I’m concerned this is a bug in MikTeX: packages have simply no way of getting the path to the `aux` directory so Pygments is working on the wrong directory.