# Error when using minted package and -output-directory option

Tags: errors, minted

I am having problem when I use the `-output-directory` option while I am using `minted`. It does not move the `.out.pyg` and `.pyg` file to the output directory and it gives me an error.
[image]

I there any solution to order minted to put the auxilary files in the output directory not in root folder?
MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{c}
  const double pi = 3.1415926535
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does it work fine (except for the location of the auxiliary files) if you remove the `-output-directory` option?

Comment: @T.Verron, yes it works

Comment: Related:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102308/minted-shows-formatted-tex-code-instead-of-intended-source

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I post this as an answer. It is not a complete answer, but it works.

If you have `main.tex` for example as your main file, an intermediate `main.pyg` is created in the root folder (despite having `-output-directory` switch) that will be deleted finally but is needed to properly typeset the source code. The solution is to make a shortcut to the `main.pyg` file and place it inside your `-output-directory` folder. The shortcut name should be `main.pyg` as well.

Answer (score 10):

[David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) suggests the following in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339933/34813):

> You need `\usepackage[outputdir=build]{minted}` to tell minted where the files went.

This works perfectly for me.