# Basic minted example prints out latex code, not source code

Tags: minted

I have this very basic .tex file:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{vendor/minted}
\begin{document}

\title{My Book}
\author{Jonathan Lipps}
\maketitle

\begin{minted}{python}
def boring(args = None):
    pass
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

(vendor/minted is the version of minted.sty I just downloaded from the GitHub page)

Rather than producing the expected output, I get a PDF with some very nicely highlighted latex gibberish, which appears to my eyes to be the latex code that should generate the python source display, not what should actually be displayed itself:

```
\makeatletter
\def\PY@reset{\let\PY@it=\relax \let\PY@bf=\relax%
    \let\PY@ul=\relax \let\PY@tc=\relax%
\let\PY@bc=\relax \let\PY@ff=\relax} \def\PY@tok#1{\csname PY@tok@#1\endcsname} \def\PY@toks#1+{\ifx\relax#1\empty\else%
\PY@tok{#1}\expandafter\PY@toks\fi} \def\PY@do#1{\PY@bc{\PY@tc{\PY@ul{%
\PY@it{\PY@bf{\PY@ff{#1}}}}}}} \def\PY#1#2{\PY@reset\PY@toks#1+\relax+\PY@do{#2}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gd\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.63,0.00,0.0 \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gu\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[ \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gt\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.27,0.8 \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gs\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gr\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.0 \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@cm\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[ \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@vg\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.4 \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@m\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40 \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@mh\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.4 \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@go\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.53,0.53,0.5 \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@ge\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@vc\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.4 \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@il\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.4 \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@cs\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[ \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@cp\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.74,0.48,0.0 \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gi\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.63,0.0 \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gh\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[ \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@ni\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[ \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nl\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.63,0.63,0.0 \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nn\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[ \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@no\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.53,0.00,0.0 \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@na\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.49,0.56,0.1 \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nb\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.0 \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nc\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[ \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nd\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.67,0.13,1.0 \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@ne\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[ \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nf\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.0 \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@si\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[ \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@s2\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.1 \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@vi\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.4 \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nt\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[ \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nv\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.4 \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@s1\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.1 \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@sh\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.1 \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@sc\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.1
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@sx\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}} \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@bp\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}} \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@c1\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25, \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@kc\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00, \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@c\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0 \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@mf\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}} \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@err\endcsname{\def\PY@bc##1{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fcolorbox[rg \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@kd\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00, \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@ss\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}} \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@sr\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.53}{##1}}} \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@mo\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}} \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@kn\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00, \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@mi\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}} \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gp\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00, \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@o\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}} \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@kr\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00, \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@s\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}} \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@kp\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}} \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@w\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.73,0.73}{##1}}} \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@kt\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.69,0.00,0.25}{##1}}} \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@ow\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.67, \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@sb\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}} \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@k\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0 \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@se\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73, \expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@sd\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,
\def\PYZbs{\char \\} \def\PYZus{\char \_} \def\PYZob{\char \{} \def\PYZcb{\char \}} \def\PYZca{\char \^} \def\PYZam{\char \&} \def\PYZlt{\char \<} \def\PYZgt{\char \>} \def\PYZsh{\char \#} \def\PYZpc{\char \%} \def\PYZdl{\char \ } \def\PYZhy{\char \-} \def\PYZsq{\char \’} \def\PYZdq{\char \"} \def\PYZti{\char \~}
% for compatibility with earlier versions \def\PYZat{ }
\def\PYZlb{[}
\def\PYZrb{]}
\makeatother
```

So my question is, how do I get it to do the right thing? Here's how I'm compiling the pdf:

```
xelatex -shell-escape myfile.tex
```

[UPDATE]

And here are all the versions of everything:

```
xelatex --version
XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014)

python --version
Python 2.7.5

pip freeze
Pygments==1.6
```

I tried both the regular `minted` that came with my TeX live distribution, and also the one I just downloaded from minted's master on GitHub (that's the one in `vendor`). I'm on a Mac, OS X 10.8.

[UPDATE]

I discovered that the problem is in the command I was using, which (contrary to what I wrote above) was actually:

```
xelatex -output-directory=build -shell-escape book/main.tex
```

Turns out the -output-directory flag causes this problem. When I run in the correct directory, everything works just fine. I'm curious though why -output-directory would cause things to fail!

[UPDATE]

This appears to be a duplicate of (at least) [Error when using minted package and -output-directory option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112953/error-when-using-minted-package-and-output-directory-option)

Perhaps this should be closed/merged?

Comment: This works fine for me. The `minted` package needs to have the python `Pygments` library installed. Perhaps you don't have this?

Comment: What version of `minted` did you download?

Comment: Works fine for me, both with minted from TeX-Live and the one I got from GitHub in folder "vendor", to replicate your approach.
Some questions to track down you problem: Wich version of minted did you get? Did you try use the minted that comes with your TeX distribution? Wich versions of Python and Pygments do you use? What's in your logfile?
Many questions, but your issue seems quite strange ;-)

Comment: Tried to respond with a comment but I'm new to StackExchange and that didn't work too well. I updated the issue instead.

Comment: I can confirm that nothing strange appears (I have Mac OS X 10.9.4, but it shouldn't be a problem).

Comment: OK. I got my tex distribution via homebrew. Will delete that and try to download it from the website instead and see if that helps.

Comment: OK, after some more investigation, looks like it was -output-directory that was causing the issue (updated description)