# Specifying a relative path in Latex document

Tags: pdftex

I have a Latex document split across multiple files (.tex). Considering the `main.tex` file includes the `intro.tex` file:

```
\begin{document}
...
\input{intro.tex}
```

Both files are side by side in the same folder. I can build this with `pdflatex` in that directory.

But I'm considering to build (call `pdflatex`) from a dedicated `build` folder (which is in the same level). I mean, `cd build` and then `pdflatex ../main.tex`.

I've noticed that building from inside it (the `build` folder) requires a modification in the `main.tex`, I need to change the path of the inputs to:

```
\input{../intro.tex}
```

So, it seems the path is relative to where the build runs from. Instead, I would like the path to be relative to the file which has the `\input` command. Is it possible?

Also, I would like to point it's mentioned [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Modular_Documents) that "... it is important to note that the paths are relative to the directory in which the main .tex file resides, not to the directory in which the included (or input) file is found. This is likely to be an issue ...", which in my understand isn't correct. As i said above, "it seems the path is relative to where the build (`pdflatex`) runs from". Right?

Comment: not really. It's pretty much always best to do `cd somewhere; latex file` than `latex somewhere/file` You can of course use `TEXINPUTS=..//: latex main` then `\input{intro}` would work

Comment: The `import` package might be usefull, http://repositorios.cpai.unb.br/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/import/import.pdf

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, what do you mean by "not really"? I've edit/add something to the question, do you agree?

Comment: I meant "no" (to the question of is it possible to  use paths relative to the main file) except tex is Turing complete, so anything's possible if you complicate the macros enough, but not always feasible. In this case just setting TEXINPUTS to include all your project files then just using `\input` with no paths seems the simplest thing to do

Comment: (if I understand it) In Brazil, we call your recommendation as "matar uma mosca com um canhão". It works, but might not be the most elegant/precise solution (in my opinion at the moment). The `import` package seems to allow relative to relative paths, don't you like it?

Comment: Related question [include - How to make the main file recognize relative paths used in the imported files? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4602/how-to-make-the-main-file-recognize-relative-paths-used-in-the-imported-files)