# minted doesn't seem to use cache when outputdir option given

Tags: minted

I am building out-of-source so my build command looks like this

```
pdflatex -shell-escape --halt-on-error -output-directory="/tmp/build" book.tex
```

I have been using minted for syntax highlighting

```
\newcommand{\mintedoptions}{cachedir=/tmp/mint}
\usepackage[\mintedoptions]{minted}
\begin{document}
\inputminted{c}{program.c}
\end{document}
```

This much was working fine, but when I tried to introduce `\begin{minted}{c}...\end{minted}` I got this error:

```
! Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted was
probably given a file that does not exist--otherwise, you may need 
the outputdir package option, or may be using an incompatible build tool.
```

This problem has [been solved](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339931/latex-minted-package-using-custom-output-directory-build/339933#339933), I applied the fix to my document

```
\newcommand{\mintedoptions}{cachedir=/tmp/mint,outputdir=/tmp/build}
```

now the document compiles apparently correctly, but the minted cache doesn't seem to be used -- compilation is very slow because all the minted code snippets are being recompiled from scratch each time

**How can I have outputdir specified and keep the cache in use?**

Here's a full MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrbook}
\newcommand{\mintedoptions}{cachedir=/tmp/mint2,outputdir=/tmp/xxx}
\usepackage[\mintedoptions]{minted}
\begin{document}
\inputminted{c}{program.c}
\begin{minted}{c}
int main ();
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Compiled with

```
mkdir /tmp/xxx && pdflatex -shell-escape --halt-on-error -output-directory="/tmp/xxx" mwe.tex
```

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206695/latexmk-outdir-with-include#comment481933_206695

Comment: sorry couldn't avoid the above:-) I don't know, possibly you could raise an issue on the minted github

Comment: Apparently this has been fixed in v2.5? https://www.texlive.info/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf#page=35