# Minted box not showing in pdf file after checking "use 'build' subdirectory" option in Texmaker

Tags: pdftex, texmaker, minted

This problem is very straight forward:
When I use PDFLaTeX in Texmaker 5.1.3 when I have not checked the box "Use a 'build' subdirectory for output files", the output to the following tex code is as one would expect, with the minted code showing on the document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cache=false, newfloat]{minted}
\begin{document}
begin code
\begin{minted}{python}
  def test:
    pass
\end{minted}
end code
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: pdf file with code]

But when I check the box [image: checkbox], the pdf ignores the code section altogether:

[image: no code]

The command of PDFLaTeX defined in the configuration of Texmaker is:

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex
```

Any idea on how to solve this? I don't like having generated files sitting around next to my main doc so unchecking the option is not a viable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem has nothing to do with Texmaker. If you use the flag `-output-directory=build` for PDFLaTeX, the problem will continue. The solution I found in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339931/latex-minted-package-using-custom-output-directory-build) answer is to specify your build folder directly on the minted package:

```
\usepackage[outputdir=build]{minted}
```

The minted package specification has an explanation for this:

> The `-output-directory` and `-aux-directory` (MiKTeX) command-line
> options for Latex cause problems for minted, because the minted
> temporary files are saved in , but minted still looks for
> them in the document root directory. There is no way to access the
> value of the command-line option so that minted can automatically look
> in the right place. But it is possible to allow the output directory
> to be specified manually as a package option.